# How to restart job in zeebe

Tags: go, zeebe

I have method, as part of zeebe workflow job. And when it fails, I want to restart all job. I found, that it can be done with NewFailJobCommand, but it seems that the job fails on the first try. How I can restart the job if it fails?

```
err := w.workflowStore.InitScanEventsTTL(ctx, scanID, job.Msg.Tenant)
    if err != nil {
        return w.client.NewFailJobCommand().JobKey(job.Key).Retries(job.Retries - 
            1).ErrorMessage(reason).Send(ctx)
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean when you say `it seems that the job fails on the first try`. Do you mean that the `InitScanEventsTTL` call always returns a non-nil value for `err`? Or that the `NewFailJobCommand` cannot be send successfully? Or is an error thrown in your code? Or that the fail command leads to an Incident in the process instance? Please provide some additional details to your question

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the retry count in the task properties in the process model.